# FFmpeg : How to apply volume filter fast in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, volume, android-ffmpeg

i am using below code for applying volume filter in ffmpeg, but its taking too long.Let's say the audio itself is for 5 minutes then applying this filter takes 3 minutes. Can someone help to speed up the process.

my command is as:

```
var command = "-i $audioPath -af volume=enable='between(t,5,10)':volume=0.25,volume=enable='between(t,15,20)':volume=0.25 $outputFile"
```

logs are:

```
2018-11-29 15:17:16.912 17250-17250/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest 
D/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest.service.AudioOverlayService: onProgress - 
---AudioVolume---- video:0kB audio:3030kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB 
global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.236199%
2018-11-29 15:17:16.913 17250-17250/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest 
D/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest.service.AudioOverlayService: onProgress - 
---AudioVolume---- bench: utime=168.977s
2018-11-29 15:17:16.915 17250-17250/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest 
D/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest.service.AudioOverlayService: onProgress - 
---AudioVolume---- bench: maxrss=65116kB
2018-11-29 15:17:16.917 17250-17250/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest 
D/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest.service.AudioOverlayService: onProgress - 
---AudioVolume---- [aac @ 0xaf5e4400] Qavg: 15833.816
2018-11-29 15:17:16.920 17250-17250/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest 
D/com.example.prashants.ffmpegtest.service.AudioOverlayService: AudioVolume 
success--------- -benchmark -threads 4 -i 
/storage/emulated/0/FFmpegTest/looped.m4a -af 
volume=enable='between(t,5,10)+between(t,15,20)':volume=0.25:eval=frame 
/storage/emulated/0/FFmpegTest/filtered_audio.m4a
```

that's the log from my android studio console

Comment: Does the file have any video?

Comment: No. its just an audio file @Gyan

Comment: How long do the following two commands take for a 5-minute audio-only file: `ffmpeg -benchmark -i in -vn -f null -` and `ffmpeg -benchmark -i in -c copy -vn -f null -`?

Comment: @Gyan 1st one takes 2 seconds and 2nd one takes 1 second

Comment: Add the full log of `ffmpeg -i in` to your Q.

Comment: @Gyan can you please suggest something.. i have already added the log...

Comment: Log is incomplete. Input file details at the end is truncated.

Comment: -i /storage/emulated/0/FFmpegTest/looped.m4a is input and output is /storage/emulated/0/FFmpegTest/filtered_audio.m4a

Comment: Yes, the log is truncated. Add -report to the filtering cmd - ffmpeg will generate a text log. Paste that in full.

Comment: @Gyan command gets failed when adding -report...
it gives error as: -- Failed to open report "ffmpeg-20181128-205923.log": Read-only file system

Comment: @Gyan can you please help on this??